# How do I count from 2 different tables in access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have two tables, one that contains information about patients visits: PatientName,DoctorName,DataOfVisit, etc and the second table that contains information about doctors: DoctorName and DoctorSpeciality.

I need to create a query that will print me the PatientName, the number of doctors that patient went to, and the number of different specialties.

If I run

```
SELECT PatientName, COUNT(VISITS.DoctorName) as DocNum,   Count(DoctorSpeciality) as SpecNum
FROM VISITS 
INNER JOIN Doctors 
ON VISITS.DoctorName = Doctors.DoctorName
GROUP BY PatientName, VISITS.DoctorName, DoctorSpeciality
```

I get the number of Doctors but not the number of Specialities and the patients are not grouped.

Comment: create query for join the tables and create a query with this for count

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you would just use `count(distinct specialty)`.  But, Access doesn't support that.

You can do what you want with two `group by`s:

```
SELECT PatientName, COUNT(*) as NumSpecialties, SUM(NumDocs) as NumDocs
FROM (SELECT PatientName, Doctors.DoctorSpeciality, COUNT(*) as NumDocs 
      FROM VISITS INNER JOIN
           Doctors 
            ON VISITS.DoctorName = Doctors.DoctorName
      GROUP BY PatientName, DoctorSpeciality
     ) as pd
GROUP BY PatientName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add DISTINCT within your COUNT() function, also you should not include the aggregate fields in your GROUP BY.

Here is how I would change the query.

```
SELECT PatientName, COUNT(DISTINCT VISITS.DoctorName) as DocNum,       
Count(DISTINCT DoctorSpeciality) as SpecNum
FROM VISITS INNER JOIN
Doctors ON VISITS.DoctorName = Doctors.DoctorName
GROUP BY PatientName
```

Answer (score 0):

use table name with fields that you want to select from db

SELECT VISITS.PatientName, COUNT(VISITS.DoctorName) as DocNum,   Count(Doctors.DoctorSpeciality) as SpecNum
FROM VISITS 
INNER JOIN Doctors 
ON VISITS.DoctorName = Doctors.DoctorName
GROUP BY PatientName, VISITS.DoctorName, DoctorSpeciality